# CMB anisotropies due to moving clusters/voids?

Tags: cosmology, potential, astrophysics, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

Apparently, there is an effect where a moving overdensity/underdensity (or an object, e.g. a galaxy, moving in an overdensity/underdensity) that is going through an evolution of its gravitational potential (due to the linear Integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect, or the non-linear version, the Rees-Sciama effect) will cause a dipole in CMB photons, with a redshifted and a blueshifted part, as shown here [1](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2019/08/aa35261-19/aa35261-19.html) (Fig. 1).

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. Can the dipole signal be more intense for the blueshifted photons in some cases?
2. I understand that this effect also can happen if a galaxy is moving through an expanding void (instead of a cluster), or for photons passing through a moving void in general. Would the signal be reversed in a void (photons being blueshifted in the direction of movement and redshifted in the opposite direction)? Or would it be exactly like in the moving overdensity?